# OpenAuth :: Do i need to Replicate OpenAuth Users table in Database to my own DB

Tags: c#, entity-framework, oauth, dotnetopenauth

This is the OpenAuth Login Mechanism. Providers are listed in the web.config.

```
protected void RegisterUser_CreatedUser(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(RegisterUser.UserName, createPersistentCookie: false);

        string continueUrl = RegisterUser.ContinueDestinationPageUrl;
        if (!OpenAuth.IsLocalUrl(continueUrl))
        {
            continueUrl = "~/";
        }
        Response.Redirect(continueUrl);
    }
```

My Question is as regards to join statements in my code where users are involved 
Example being

```
select * from ResourcesAvailablePerUser,Users
where resourceid = @resourceid
and Users.userid = @userid
and Users.userid = ResourcesAvailablePerUser.userid
```

Since OpenAuth Database is different from my DB, and so i do not have the table of users in my DB..

So my Further Question is do i have to modify the above code by adding REPLICATION CODE TO THE OPENAUTH CODE AND MAINTAIN A REPLICATED USERS TABLE in my own database..basically i do not understand why my table of users should be maintained outside my own DB if iam right about it.

> This is the OpenAuth Code to validate users

```
    protected void RegisterUser_CreatedUser(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(RegisterUser.UserName, createPersistentCookie: false);

`//DO I HAVE TO ADD CODE HERE TO REPLICATE THE TABLE OF USERS IN MY OWN DB.`

            string continueUrl = RegisterUser.ContinueDestinationPageUrl;
            if (!OpenAuth.IsLocalUrl(continueUrl))
            {
                continueUrl = "~/";
            }
            Response.Redirect(continueUrl);
        }
```